# TFS - Build Service Starts and then throws a HTTP code 500: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have been working on restoring a build server (tfs 2012) from a backup and all manner of things got messed up (the tfsservice account password had been altered and I had to go to every service and app pool on the box and update it). Once sql was backup I was able to update the password via the TFS admin console app. Then I was able to re-register the build service and add a controller and a build agent. It starts briefly and shows green for a few seconds before stopping and a "details ..." button appears next to the Build Service. If I click the details button I see the following

"Please contact your administrator. There was an error contacting the server. Technical information (for administrator): HTTP code 500: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException"

I have checked the http bindings in iis for the tfs site and there is only the one "*:8080"

I tried hardcoding it to the ip on the box and I still get the same error. If I go to one of the client machines and try and queue a build it shows the build server as being offline.

I have also checked for multiple host headers and the memory utilization which are the most common responses to this particular issue. Neither of them seem to be the cause or the solution.

Any ideas or suggestions are welcome I have run out of ideas to try here. Thanks in advance for any help you have to offer.

EDIT -- also found this in the log: Build machine MyMachine lost connectivity to message queue tfsmq://buildservicehost-25/.

Comment: Are there any useful info in event logs on the build server?

Comment: The most useful log entry is the one above that says it lost connectivity to the message queue which is then followed by the 500 error. That error is repeated a ton. But there is unfortunately nothing more helpful than that.

Comment: Why are you restoring a build server from backup? Why not just create a new one?

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. I got a new one stood up and upgraded the database from the original install and that seemed to work. Having some issues getting builds completed but at least it seems to be working.